# Django - view sql query without publishing migrations

Tags: django

When I make changes to some models, I want to view the SQL the django would be running to implement those changes on the DB.

The normal way of doing this would be to do 'makemigrations appname'. This will generate a migration, let's say, - '0001_someName.py'. Then one can do 'sqlmigrate 0001_someName.py'

But I want to view the sql directly, without having to create that intermediate migration. Can this be done?

Answer (score 150):

Use the [`sqlmigrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate) command from `manage.py`.

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate <appname> <migration number eg. 0001 or 0004>
```

will display the SQL statements for a specific migration of the app.

Comment: I have a data migration I want to analyze but `sqlmigrate` doesn't display anything for that. Is that how it supposed to be? Does this only display when schema changing migration command are executed?

Answer (score 9):

These existing answers are not enough, as I found out trying to follow them.  First detect and make the migration script for your app:

```
manage.py makemigrations app
```

Make note of the four-digit migration number which starts the filename.  Then print the SQL with:

```
manage.py sqlmigrate app 0002  # <-- number here
```

When finished, remove the file before it gets run or committed:

```
rm app/migrations/0002_auto_8675309.py
```

Comment: that's help! thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Django does not provide that option. You can always create the migration, run `sqlmigrate`, and delete the migration file. As long as it isn't applied with `migrate`, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
python manage.py sql <appname>
```

-- Prints the CREATE TABLE SQL statements for the given app name(s).

```
python manage.py sqlall <appname>
```

-- Prints the CREATE TABLE and initial-data SQL statements for the given app name(s).

You'll find detail documentation here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/

Comment: those are not `manage.py` commands, but `django-admin` commands, as you also link to

Comment: @Steen They're the same thing, it even says so in the link

Comment: These commands are deprecated in Django 1.9 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9 @amit-sharma's answer is the next best option

Comment: Thank you, you save my time! With Django 1.6 very works well ;)